# Angular: best directive to switch display layout - ng-show?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to implement a result list with multiple types of display (line, grid, detailed or not, etc, ...)

What is the best approach to do this?

I was thinking of using `ng-show` but I'm wondering about performances, do hidden elements are processed in a way or is it ok to have like 4 or 5 types of layout and display one at a time using `ng-show`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-switch` instead. The difference is that it only renders elements that meet the condition. But then again, if you pre-load them initially and just show/hide, the switches between them will be fast while the initial load will be longer (slightly). While with `ng-switch` you will have a certain rendering time for each display.

I would say that it's OK to use `ng-show` unless you have a lot of data. Try it out and see what works better for you.

Even `ng-view` could be an option.